# Top results by rank and limit each group while balancing rank distribution

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, algorithm

I am pulling data back that has a list of Employees and Sites they have serviced with a Rank based on a bunch of unrelated logic.

I need to send surveys to each Employee's top 3 Sites by Rank.  But I cannot send more than 3 surveys per Site.

I've tried a couple ways to script this but it always ends up inefficient, the distribution is off and ends up needing to be done manually. Is there a nice algorithm for this or something I could do in SQL (SQL Server 2017) to achieve this?

---

Here is some example data and one of the issues I run into when trying to script it.

In bold are each employee's top 3 sites.

```
| Employee | Site | Rank  |
|----------|------|-------|
| Andrew   | AAF  | 4     |
| Andrew   | AAS  | 4     |
| Andrew   | OP   | 4     |
| Andrew   | AAL  | 3     |
| Andrew   | ZZ   | 3     |
| Alex     | MI   | 22    |
| Alex     | TM   | 21    |
| Alex     | PF   | 20    |
| Alex     | QW   | 20    |
| Alex     | LE   | 17    |
| Clarice  | NY   | 25    |
| Clarice  | MD   | 21    |
| Clarice  | TM   | 16    |
| Clarice  | MS   | 12    |
| Clarice  | PO   | 10    |
| Devon    | OC   | 48    |
| Devon    | KY   | 33    |
| Devon    | TM   | 32    |
| Devon    | AV   | 28    |
| Devon    | ZQ   | 28    |
| James    | ZZ   | 50    |
| John     | AV   | 37    |
| John     | AZ   | 32    |
| John     | AS   | 31    |
| John     | ZZ   | 31    |
| Matthew  | WK   | 22    |
| Matthew  | MI   | 19    |
| Matthew  | TM   | 15    |
| Matthew  | PS   | 14    |
| Matthew  | ZZ   | 9     |
| Mike     | ZX   | 74    |
| Mike     | AAL  | 46    |
| Mike     | AAS  | 30    |
| Mike     | AAT  | 27    |
| Mike     | AAU  | 22    |
| Phillip  | AAS  | 48    |
| Phillip  | ZZ   | 25    |
| Phillip  | AAT  | 19    |
| Phillip  | AAF  | 15    |
| Phillip  | AAV  | 13    |
| Robert   | AV   | 36    |
| Robert   | AS   | 34    |
| Robert   | AW   | 29    |
| Robert   | DW   | 26    |
| Robert   | AZ   | 17    |
| Scott    | V    | 19    |
| Scott    | U    | 16    |
| Scott    | AV   | 15    |
| Scott    | DW   | 14    |
| Scott    | CH   | 12    |
| Sam      | AAS  | 58    |
| Sam      | ZZ   | 49    |
| Sam      | AAF  | 31    |
| Sam      | AAV  | 29    |
| Sam      | AAR  | 1     |
```

I check for exceptions where a site is listed more than 3 times in the employee's top 3 sites.  For each group of exceptions I remove the first entry I can.

1. On first check, AAS exceeds 3 surveys per site.

   ```
    | Employee | Site | Score  |
    |----------|------|--------|
    | Sam      | AAS  | 58     |-- Delete
    | Phillip  | AAS  | 48     |
    | Mike     | AAS  | 30     |
    | Andrew   | AAS  | 4      |
   ```

   ```
    Sam's top 3 sites are now:
        * ZZ - 49
        * AAF - 31
        * AAV - 29
   ```
2. Checking again, TM now exceeds 3 surveys per site.

   ```
    | Employee | Site | Rank   |
    |----------|------|--------|
    | Devon    | TM   | 32     |-- Delete
    | Alex     | TM   | 21     |
    | Clarice  | TM   | 16     |
    | Matthew  | TM   | 15     |
   ```

   ```
    Devon's top 3 sites are now:
         * OC - 48
         * KY - 33
         * AV - 28
   ```
3. Checking again, AV now exceeds 3 surveys per site.

   ```
    | Employee | Site | Rank    |
    |----------|------|---------|
    | John     | AV   | 37      |-- Delete
    | Robert   | AV   | 36      |
    | Devon    | AV   | 28      |
    | Scott    | AV   | 15      |
   ```

   ```
    John's top 3 sites are now:
         * AZ - 32
         * AS - 31
         * ZZ - 31
   ```
4. And lastly, checking again, ZZ now exceeds 3 surveys per site.

   ```
    | Employee | Site | Rank   |
    |----------|------|--------|
    | James*   | ZZ   | 50     |  
    | Sam      | ZZ   | 49     |-- Delete
    | John     | ZZ   | 31     |
    | Phillip  | ZZ   | 25     |
    * James only has one Site, so I have to skip him.
   ```

   ```
    Sam's Top 3 sites are now:
         * AAF - 31
         * AAV - 29
         * AAR - 1
   ```

Sam now has a Rank 1 record in his Top 3, but if I would have removed Phillip instead of Sam it wouldn't have went through steps 3&4 and Sam would still have all high ranking sites.

In the real data there around 300 employees, 700 sites, an employee could have worked on ~1-50 sites and could have closed ~1-100 tickets per site.  With the added records it causes more iterations and throws things off way further causing the rank distribution to be really unbalanced.

Comment: Could you just sort the sites by rank and send surveys to the top associated site-employee pairs as long as a site/employee hasn't been repeated more than three times (in which case ignore this entry), and continue until each employee has gotten exactly three surveys or the list is exhausted?

Comment: Your conflicts rule is sufficiently complicated that I would strongly recommend pulling the raw data back into PHP, and then analyzing it in custom code.

Comment: How do you decide which order to do these eliminations? As you say *"would have removed Phillip instead of Sam it wouldn't have went through steps 3&4 and Sam would still have all high ranking sites."* If it makes no difference then there are some nice solutions using grouping and window functions

Comment: You also say *"James only has one Site, so I have to skip him."* but what is the logic of that?

Comment: I don't have a good way of deciding which to eliminate, the way that worked the best for me was eliminating the highest ranked record in that group of sites.  Just under the assumption that the employee with the largest rank would have a better chance of having a higher ranked record to replace it with.

Comment: In the example James only performed work at one site (ZZ).  I need to send out 3 surveys for every employee, unless they haven't been to 3 sites within the quarter and criteria.

Comment: Something like this might work? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4824b21b21e914c188926c308366ae8

Comment: This is so close, thank you so much!  Is there a way to prioritize making sure that all the employees are included and getting 3 surveys sent (or the max available up to 3, 1 in the case of James who only went to one site)?

Comment: For the example I believe the outcome should look like this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a3a0d02277a100d3eb2acf1548cfbfc).     My apologies, I wish I would have known about that tool before making my post, I could have been more clear.